Unable to send message from javascript injected into webview - ipcRenderer undefined
I am wanting to send messages from javascript injected into a webview element using webview.executeJavaScript, to main or renderer scripts.  What I found in several places on the web sounds pretty straightforward: Add const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron'); to the webview preload script, then call ipcRenderer.send() or ipcRenderer.sendToHost() (depending on the source I was reading) from the webview javascript content.  However, in all my attempts, I get errors saying ipcRenderer is not defined in the injected javascript.  Maybe this works if the ipcRenderer call is in the page loaded into the webview (but not for injected js), but I cannot test that as I have no control over the downloaded content.
One thing I looked at talked about using webContents instead:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/web-contents#contentssendchannel-args
but that didn't work either.
Another said that objects attached to window in the preload script would be accessible in the webview content script, but that didn't work either.
https://www.reddit.com/r/electronjs/comments/8nv8fv/communication_to_site_inside_webview/
Here is my code:
index.html:
<webview id="test_webview" preload="webview_preload.js" src="http://192.168.1.182/"></webview>

OR
<webview id="test_webview" preload="webview_preload.js" src="http://192.168.1.182/" disablewebsecurity></webview>

renderer.js:
function init() {
  let wv = document.getElementById("test_webview");
  wv.addEventListener('dom-ready', () => {
    wv.executeJavaScript('alert("javascript has been injected into webview"); try { ipcRenderer.send("ping"); } catch(e) { alert(e); }; try { webContents.send("ping"); } catch(e) { alert(e); }; try { window.sendData("ping"); } catch(e) { alert(e); }');
  });
}

window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", init);

webview_preload.js:
const { ipcRenderer, webContents } = require('electron');

window.sendData = (data) => {
  ipcRenderer.send("ping");
}

alert("webview_preload.js has been loaded into webview");

The alert("javascript has been injected into webview") verifies that the js is being injected, but the subsequent 3 try/catches show me all my attempts fail, showing that neither ipcRenderer, webContents, nor window.sendData is defined.  alert("webview_preload.js has been loaded into webview") verifies that the preload script is loaded.
I have verified that ipcRenderer.send() works when called directly from the preload script.

Where have you seen that you should write window.sendData in the preload? Have you read the IPC docs?

I provided a link where that was suggested in my post.  It was just a suggestion that I thought I would try after scouring for a solution since nothing else was working.  Yes, I have read the docs.

Well I can see why the window.sendData "trick" didn't work.  Explicitly stated: "This means that the window object that your preload script has access to is actually a different object than the website would have access to. For example, if you set window.hello = 'wave' in your preload script and context isolation is enabled, window.hello will be undefined if the website tries to access it." - https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation.  I assume that would also apply to injected code.

Herein lies the problem: Context isolation.
The window.sendData in my code was the right idea, and would work if context isolation is disabled, but that is not recommended.  Context isolation is the default since Electron 12.  Prior to Electron 12, the window.sendData() code would have worked out of the box.  (The Reddit comment I linked was probably prior to Electron 12.)
From electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/context-isolation:
With context isolation enabled,

This means that the window object that your preload script has access
to is actually a different object than the website would have access
to. For example, if you set window.hello = 'wave' in your preload
script and context isolation is enabled, window.hello will be
undefined if the website tries to access it.

So we need to explicitly expose the sendData() method using a contextBridge:
https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/context-bridge
We replace:
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

window.sendData = (data) => {
  ipcRenderer.send("ping");
}

With:
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld('api', {
  sendData: (data) => {
    ipcRenderer.send("ping");
  },
});

Then in the  content script, we access sendData this way:
window.api.sendData("some data");

Much thanks to @MarshallOfSound on this Github issue:
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/28410
who took the time to guide me through my problem.
